# Drupal - personalize content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, image-segmentation

I am using Drupal 7, and I came across with a problem that I hope someone can help with.

How can I give my users a way to add personalize content to the site, for example I have a content type with an image and a body? I want to give the users control to segment the image and the body according to some business rules.

I tried the personalize module but this might be complicated for them.

Comment: Are we meant to understand what "segment the image and the body according to some business rules" means?

Comment: For example user that come from untited states will see one image and a user that come from london will see a diffrent image.

Comment: There are many ways to allow users to personalize their experience. Fields on the user object, bookmarked lists of content, and many many more. Without more detail it's hard to say more than: yes, what you want is probably possible.

Comment: are u doing this with module?
and just to say more i am not using the drupal users i have an external API and my users come from there so its not the user itself that give the rules and change the page , its  according to population that i am doing the segmentation as the site owner.
i will be glad to see an example if you have.

Comment: clearer title/sentences